# How to Find Child , Parent and their childs and parents in chain according to the given Id in SQL server table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I have a Group Table in SQL Server with the following structure.

```
Id(int), 
Name(nvarchar)
```

A group can be sub group of other group/s. To maintain this I have a following table structure.

```
ParentGroupId(int), 
SubGroupId (int)
```

I need a query which returns all the parents and children and their parents and children till nth level according to the given group id.

For more details please look at the following image.

[image]

In the above image, if I give group id like `G6` the query should find the complete chain and return group ids (G1, G2, G4, G5, G6, G7, G10, G13, G8, G9 , G11 , G12 , G14, G15)

any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks in advance.

Comment: means your table is like (id,name,parentgroupid,subgroupid) where parentgroupid and subgroupid are 'id' of other groups. correct? or can you provide sample data?

Comment: no i have two tables 1st called Group with two columns (Id, Name) and 2nd one is SubGroups with column (ParentGroupId, subGroupId)

Comment: can you provide sample data on sqlfiddle OR in question?

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this:

1- to add a calculated field called path in the SubGroup table

2- the default value of this field is GetChildren which is a recursive function in sql

3- the GetChildren code will be:

```
create function GetChildren(@id as int) -- id is the value of sub group
returns varchar(max)
as
begin
    declare @parent int,
            @path varchar(max)
    select @parent=ParentGroupId from SubGroup where SubGroupId=@id
    if(@parent is null)
         return ltrim(rtrim(str(@id)))
    select @path=Path from SubGroup where SubGroupId=@parent
    if(@path is not null)
         return @path + '\' + ltrim(rtrim(str(@id)));
    set @path=dbo.GetChildren(@parent) + '\' + ltrim(rtrim(str(@id)))
    return @path
end
```

4- you put the computed column of the Path field as dbo.GetChildren(SubGroupId)

5- you can get all the children  by doing the query like: 
   -- you will get the id of G4 for example say IdG4 ( int)
   select * from SubGroup where Path like ltrim(rtrim(str(IdG4))) + '%' -- get all fields that its path starting with the id of G4

after the test

---

table Groups contains

```
Id  Name
1   G1
2   G2
3   G3
4   G4
5   G5
6   G6
7   G7
8   G8
9   G9
10  G10
11  G11
12  G12
13  G13
14  G14
15  G15
16  G16
17  G17
```

table SubGroups

---

```
SubGroupId  ParentGroupId   Id  Path
4   1   1   1\4
5   1   2   1\5
10  4   3   1\4\10
11  10  4   1\4\10\11
12  10  5   1\4\10\12
6   1   6   2\6
13  5   7   1\5\13
6   2   8   2\6
7   2   9   2\7
8   6   10  2\6\8
14  8   11  2\6\8\14
15  8   12  2\7\9\15
15  9   13  2\7\9\15
9   7   14  2\7\9
16  3   15  3\16
17  3   16  3\17
```

select * from SubGroups where Path Like '1%' --( G1) and result will be

```
SubGroupId  ParentGroupId   Id  Path
4   1   1   1\4
5   1   2   1\5
10  4   3   1\4\10
11  10  4   1\4\10\11
12  10  5   1\4\10\12
13  5   7   1\5\13
```

so from this you will notice that the children and sub children of G1 is (4,5,10,11,12,13) that correspond to (G4,G5,G10,G11,G12,G13)

---

for a complete solution: please refer to this link [Graphs and Graph algorithms in T-SQL](http://hansolav.net/sql/graphs.html)

hope this will help you

Comment: No it's return only the child not the complete chain so it's not working in my scenario  like group id G6 should find the complete chain and return group ids (G1, G2, G4, G5, G6, G7, G10, G13, G8, G9 , G11 , G12 , G14, G15)

Comment: using the same technique, instead of making Like '1%' then make the query in this way: select * from SubGroup where '\' + Path + '\' like '%\6\%'; then you will get all connections with node 6, but your settings will not help you to get what you asking since in my answer you need to add more rows inot SubGroups table

Comment: in my solution, i added the parent of node 6 are ( G1, G2) but you need also to add (G13, G8) in order to get the result you want

Comment: my solution will not give you what you want, i edited the solution and i put a link that contains a solution ( Graphs and graph algorithm in t-sql) , hope this will help you